Необязательное поле регулярного выражения
Как сделать так что бы регулярное выражение /^(?:брак)\s?([^]+)?/i принимало только "брак" или "брак f", что бы "бракf" не принимало
Просто "браки" срабатывает

\s+ вот так, например

не работает  https://regex101.com/r/liYqMw/1

Тут очень важно, какой язык программирования.

Очевидно, так: ^(?:брак)(|\s+([a-z]+))?$
брак и (или пусто, или \s+([a-z]+)).

спасибо, второй элемент в коде будет как 1-ый аргумент или 2-ой

к сожалению не даёт поставить отзыв

Альтернатива (|\s+ не нужна, достаточно было бы ^(?:брак)(\s+[a-z]+)?

не работает так вообще

Ну да, конец $ приделать забыл

огромное вам спасибо

По-моему, 2 группы здесь лишние. ^брак(?:\s+[a-z]+)?$
